# Kamel install command not working. Error: cannot find automatically a registry where to push images

Tags: groovy, kubernetes, apache-camel

I'm new to the Apache Kamel. I have installed Kubernetes on master machine and then I downloaded the binary file "kamel" and placed in the path "/usr/bin". My versions are,

```
Camel K Client 0.3.3
```

My kubernetes master and kubeDNS is running fine. When I tried to install kamel on kubernetes cluster by using command "kamel install" as per the documentation, I'm getting the following error,

```
Error: cannot find automatically a registry where to push images
```

I don't know what does this new command does

```
"kamel install --cluster-setup"
```

After running the above command the response is like this,

```
Camel K cluster setup completed successfully
```

I tried to run a small integration script like

```
"kamel run hello.groovy --dev"
```

My groovy file code is,

```
from("timer:tick?period=3s")
.setBody().constant("Hello World from Camel K!!!")
.to("log:message")
```

but the pods are getting hanged, its status is pending.

```
camel-k-operator-587b579567-92xlk   0/1     Pending   0          26m
```

Can you please help me in this regard? Thanks a lot for your time.

References I used are,
https://github.com/apache/camel

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the container registry where camel-k can publish/retrieve images, you can do it by editing camel-k's integration platform

```
oc edit integrationplatform camel-k
```

or upon installation

```
kamel install --registry=...
```

Comment: Hi Luca, registry means do I need to provide any docker url?

Comment: Thank you, now I have created a repository on my docker hub account and added the name to the command "kamel install --registry='abc/demo'. Camel k installed successfully on default namespace message returned. But now when I tried to run my groovy script it hanged with "integration 'hello' created". Can you help me here? Thanks a lot for your time Luca. By the way I'm using AWS instance, where I have installed Kubernetes as master.

Comment: Any help? I'm still facing the issue. Kamel run getting hanged after integration is created. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi @Luca, any help? Thanks.

Comment: looks like you are cross-posting here and on an issue on the camel-k project, I would suggest to provide details and logs on the github issue and stop cross-posting as it does not help at all.

Comment: Thank you Luca, but I have already raised an issue on github long ago, no one has answered to my question. That is why I'm cross-posting here and there. Not able to find a single resource for debugging the issue. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: cross-posting does not help and it is not the first time you are doing it, I see now that you have opened the same issues again on camel-k instead of following up on the very first issue. 

Again, this does not help.

It would be nice if you just choose one issue, provide logs and maybe do a little bit of research about how to provide your own registry on a vanilla kubernetes (or digg with your provider about the options it provides).

Comment: Sure Luca. Definitely I'll consider your suggestion. Thank you and I apologise for the inconveniences caused by me. Thanks for your time once again.